# Show $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \sin (n x) d x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

> Let $ a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b, $ and $ f \in C^{1}([a, b]) . $ Show
>   $
> \lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int \limits_{a}^{b} f(x) \sin (n x) d x=0$.

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Integrate the thing that osciallates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is known as Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma. Actually, it holds as long
as $f$ is Lebesgue integrable over $[a,b]$. Differentiability of
$f$ is not needed.

Proof: Firstly, if $f$ is of the form $f=1_{[c,d]}$ for
some $a\leq c\leq d\leq b$, the proposition is true by direct
calculation. By linearity, the proposition is true for all step functions
(i.e., linear span of functions of the form $1_{[c,d]}$). Finally,
the class of step function is dense in $L^{1}[a,b]$ in the sense:
Given an integrable function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon>0$,
there exists a step function $g:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such
that $||f-g||_{1}:=\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)-g(x)|\,dx<\varepsilon$.

Given $\varepsilon>0$, choose a step function $g$ such that $||f-g||_{1}<\varepsilon/2$.
Since $\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\sin(nx)dx\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$,
there exists $N$ such that 
$$
\left|\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\sin(nx)dx\right|<\varepsilon/2
$$
whenever $n\geq N$. For any $n\geq N$, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \left|\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\sin(nx)dx\right|\\
 & \leq & \left|\int_{a}^{b}\left[f(x)-g(x)\right]\sin(nx)dx\right|+\left|\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\sin(nx)dx\right|\\
 & \leq & ||f-g||_{1}+\left|\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\sin(nx)dx\right|\\
 & < & \varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\sin(nx)dx=0$.

Comment: Even if we limit the discussion on Riemann integral, the proposition should not be phrased as requiring that $f\in C^1[a,b]$.
Actually, the proposition continues to hold if $f$ is just continuous.

Without invoking anything about measure theory and Lebesgue integral, the proposition can be proved as long as $f$ is continuous.
Again, the proposition holds for any function of the form $1_{[c,d]}$.
By linearlity, the proposition holds for any step functions.

Comment: Observe that $f$, being continuous on the compact set $[a,b]$, is uniformly continuous.
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Choose $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon/2$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$.
Choose a partition $a=x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n = b$ such that $|x_i - x_{i-1}|<\delta$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$.
Define $g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_{i-1}) 1_{[x_{i-1},x_i)}(x) + f(b) 1_{\{b\}}(x)$.

Then $g$ is a step function and $\sup_{x\in[a,b]} |f(x)-g(x)| \leq \varepsilon/2$...

Answer (score 2):

Define $u = f(x)$, $u′ = f′(x)$, $v= -\frac{1}{n}\cos(nx)$ and $v′= \sin(nx)$.

Next apply the formula for integration by parts:
$$
\int_{a}^{b} u(x) v^′(x) d x
=[u(x) v(x)]_{a}^{b} - \int_{a}^{b} u^′(x) v(x) d x.
$$

Hence, you will get:
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \sin(nx) d x
= -\frac{1}{n}\left[f(x) \cos(nx) \right]_{a}^{b} + \frac{1}{n}\int_{a}^{b} f′(x) \cos(nx) d x
$$
Finally apply the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$.

Comment: SO ... the $C^1$ case is much, much easier than the general R-L lemma.  Presumably this is what the OP was supposed to do (on his own).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Integration by parts+ $f'$ is continous, hence bounded on $[a,b]$.